# Executing one bean before another

Tags: java, spring, spring-4

Right now I have the following two beans defined in my controller which are connecting to two different databases. The two beans in the current scenario
are executing at the same time as soon as controller receives `doc_id` and  `empID_` from the webservice call. I don't want this to happen.

**CURRENT SCENARIO:**

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/showEmpDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showEmpDetails
        (
            @RequestParam(value="doc_id", defaultValue="0") String doc_id,
            @RequestParam(value="emp_id", defaultValue="1234") String empID_
        ) 
        {    String jsonString = "";
            try {
                // Bean 1 defined for an Oracle database    
                EmployeeDao empDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("empDao");

                // Bean 2 defined for different Oracle database
                EmployeeDao empForValueDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("empValueDao");

                List<ShowDescription> beanONE = empForValueDao.getemployeeDetails(empID_);
                List<ShowDescription> beanTWO = empDao.getCompanyShowDocument(doc_id);
                } 
              return JsonString;
        }
```

**EXPECTED SCENARIO:**

I want the `beanONE` to execute first, return a value back in the controller after calling  the `getemployeeDetails` method and then pass that value at 
the time of second bean call next to `doc_id` as shown below. In this manner the SQL query I have used inside the `getCompanyShowDocument` method can make 
use of this value and get me the results I am expecting.

```
@RequestMapping(value="/showEmpDetails", method=RequestMethod.GET)
        public String showEmpDetails
        (
            @RequestParam(value="doc_id", defaultValue="0") String doc_id,
            @RequestParam(value="emp_id", defaultValue="1234") String empID_
        ) 
        {    String jsonString = "";
            try {

                 // Bean 1 defined for different Oracle database
                EmployeeDao empForValueDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("empValueDao");


                // Bean 2 defined for an Oracle database    
                EmployeeDao empDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("empDao");



                List<ShowDescription> beanONE = empForValueDao.getemployeeDetails(empID_);
                List<ShowDescription> beanTWO = empDao.getCompanyShowDocument(doc_id,returnedValue);
                } 
              return JsonString;
        }
```

In XML I have the beans defined as follows :

```
 <bean id="empDao" class="abc.edg.myproj.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl"> 
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="DB_ONE"/></property>
    </bean> 

    <bean id="empValueDao" class="abc.edg.myproj.dao.impl.EmployeeDaoImpl"> 
        <property name="dataSource"><ref bean="DB_TWO"/></property>
    </bean>
```

Is it possible to achieve what I described above? Please advise. Thanks

Adding `getemployeeeDetails` method below as requested in the comment:

```
public List<ShowDescription>  getemployeeDetails(String empID) throws DaoException
        {


            DataSource ds = null;
            Connection conn = null;
            PreparedStatement pstmt2 = null;
            ResultSet rs2 = null;
            List<ShowDescription> employeeValue = new ArrayList<ShowDescription>();

            try {
                ds = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource();
                conn = ds.getConnection();
                pstmt2 = conn.prepareStatement(selectValueSQL);
                pstmt2.setString(1, empID);                 

                rs2 = pstmt2.executeQuery();            
                while(rs2.next()) {             
                    ShowDescription employeeRecord = new ShowDescription(); 
                    employeeRecord.setEmployeeValue(rs2.getString("value"));
                    employeeValue.add(employeeRecord);

                    System.out.println("I am inside getemployeeDetails method to get the cvtermPropValue");
                    System.out.println(employeeRecord.getEmployeeValue()); // Prints the value 

                }
            } catch(Throwable th) {
                //some code
            } finally {
                // Closing all resources here
            }       

            return employeeValue;
        }
```

Comment: What makes you think that they're executed concurrently? Because they are not. And your second example already returns the values you need. What you call `beanONE` is the returned result.

Comment: Something in your code doesn't add up. If your `getemployeeDetails` doesn't return a list, the code wouldn't compile. Can you please add `getemployeeDetails` method to the description?

Comment: @AlexeySoshin Added the method. When I tried to print the contents of `beanONE` like the following :
`System.out.println(beanONE);` I got the following:
`[abc.edg.myproj.domain.ShowDescription@4de0d4f]`
which is basically the location of the java class `ShowDescription`. How can I retrieve the value here which I can use to pass
while calling the method using `beanTWO`  The following line in the method prints what I want `System.out.println(employeeRecord.getEmployeeValue());`

Comment: But you return list of values, not a single value. SO you should pass the entire list to your second method.

Comment: Could you please tell me how to do that?

Comment: Something like `List<ShowDescription> beanTWO = empDao.getCompanyShowDocument(doc_id,beanONE)` should work. You can post signature of your second method.

Comment: Okay, when you say `You can post signature of your second method`, would you like me to add the `getCompanyShowDocument` method here?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158632/discussion-between-alexey-soshin-and-dan).